# Ubuntu Crashes down because of mouse movement

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, mouse, ubuntu-20.04

My VM ubuntu is crashing because of an unknown reason and i get this dot shown in the picture bellow:

[image]

I get this error whenever i try to scroll or select text using my mouse.
I don't know how to fix so if anyone is familiar please help me

Comment: Are you running your Ubuntu distribution as guest OS inside a VirtualBox or as host?

Comment: @Raj guest OS in Vmware